# Safari mobile ignoring prevent default

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, mobile, safari

I am using `e.preventdefault()` on a link which is in an infowindow on google maps.

It works as expected on the desktop where the link doesn't visit the `href` but on Safari it seems to ignore it and visits the link as if no JavaScript is loaded.

It is clearly loading the javascript because google maps along with lots of markers and the info windows are loading fine.

The code for the link is this:

```
$('.infowindow .more, .infowindow h3 a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
                        
    /* Loading content from external html file */
    $('#content .content').html('<p class="loading"><img src="images/icons/loader.gif" alt="Loading content..."></p>');
    $('#content .content').load($(this).attr('href') + ' #content > *', function() {
```

Obviously, the code carries on from here with other bits and bobs.

Has anyone else had any issues or knows a solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
e.preventDefault();
```

append at the end of that function

```
return false;
```

Then clicked `<a>` element will not redirect to anywhere.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  Neither seem to work unfortunately.  I am thinking it is an error with my javascript but firebug shows no errors at all.

Comment: Try to `alert(1);` at the end of function and check if allert box appears.

Comment: The alert appears but it is in a lightbox type thing because the link is inside google maps.  I am wondering whether google maps is doing something on mobile devices to stop it from working?

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here, but I'm having the same problem in 2019. I was able to fix this by putting preventDefault in the html element itself:

```html
<a href="http://dontvisitthis.com" onclick="event.preventDefault()">click</a>
```

The jquery event handler still fires on click.